Is there a way to get the name of the failing job in a GitHub workflow
I have a pipeline workflow running in GitHub actions. At the end of this pipeline I added a job that runs if anything else failed (using if: failure()) and sends me a message about the failure.
If possible, I'd like the message to include the name of the job or even step that caused the workflow to fail.
I didn't find anything for this in the GitHub documentation. Does someone here know about some context variable or other functionality that could help me here?
I know you can get the result of a certain job with jobs.<job_id>.result or even the outcome of a step with steps.<step_id>.outcome, but I don't want to manually check each job I have in the workflow - it should also work automatically with newly added jobs/steps.
I also don't want to create a manual workaround by manually exporting some kind of failure result from each job in case it fails. If that's the only way, I'd rather leave this information out of the message.

You could use GitHub CLI, which is present on ubuntu-latest runners to invoke workflow run jobs REST API:
gh api /repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/actions/runs/$GITHUB_RUN_ID/jobs | jq '.jobs[]| select (.conclusion == "failure") | .name, .head_branch, (.steps[]|select(.conclusion == "failure")|.name)'

You will get three lines:
job name
branch
step name


Does it work from the currently running workflow? The link to the REST API docs' link for jobs would be helpful. I believe this is the link (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-jobs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-jobs-for-a-workflow-run).

Yes, the environment variables are only available on the runner: GITHUB_REPOSITORY and RUN_ID which make it much easier to run from inside a workflow.

I set the same env vars locally while working with gh. Last time I checked, some info from the REST API wasn't available until the workflow is finished hence the question.

Workflow run API is available from inside the workflow run.
